# how to write date in a text file asynchronously in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to export a report file (text format) of a big data. In this case, actually I have two problems.

1. Is it possible to create or open a text file then write a data into it several times on Angular?
2. If yes How to make it asynchronously?

Comment: Do you want to open a text file on the client or on the server?

Comment: Totally angular works on client side, so my question is limited to client side.

Comment: The only way to read a file is to select it using a form input and the only way to write a file is to download it.